# Scrape / Extract Wikipedia Category Taxonomies into UI

Tags: database, data-visualization, scraping, wikimedia

I would like to know how to build a visual taxonomy tree from the categories on Wikipedia as a seed; are there any existing tools which might be able to be used in order to extract this type of information, format it for this use, & what I would have to do in order to use them.

Extract the titles & links to all of the related Categories & SubCategories for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Energy and put them into a DB for use with something like d3js {under consideration; although not a final decision - as ease of work, interface operation, cross compatibility, and extensibility are stronger considerations.}

Phylogenetic / Taxonomy tree visualization 
ie: one branch:

- en.wikipedia /wiki/Category:Energy
- en.wikipedia /wiki/Category:Energy_infrastructure
- en.wikipedia /wiki/Category:Energy_infrastructure_by_continent
- en.wikipedia /wiki/Category:Energy_infrastructure_in_Europe
- en.wikipedia /wiki/Category:Energy_infrastructure_in_Spain

I am exploring en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox to play around with the information given; however, I am only getting topical information eg: 29 Subcategories w/ 41 pages.

Something like this would be a success:
[image: Responsive Taxonomy Tree]

**General Reference**:

- http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2013/06/21/messing-around-wih-d3-js-and-hierarchical-data/ && http://hacks.michelepasin.org/subjectsviz/d3tree [desired end user interface to look drastically different; however, the same structure here]
- https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ACategoryTree&target=Top_level&mode=categories&namespaces= && https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Project:Categories

Answer (score 1):

The Mediawiki software includes such a "visual taxonomy tree" feature, it is accessible here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:CategoryTree

You have to specify the root, and it shows the tree folded by default, very similar to the image in the question:

[image]